# Does the rate of heat dissipation slow as the temperature differential between the heated object and the surrounding environment decreases?

Tags: thermodynamics

Does the rate of heat dissipation slow as the temperature differential between the heated object and the surrounding environment decreases, or is it constant?

To put this into context, picture the following scenario:

A spherical piece of copper heated to 100C is suspended in air at 20C.

Comment: [See Newton's law of cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer#Newton.27s_law_of_cooling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases, the rate of heat transfer will increase with the temperature difference. This is generally true in conduction, convection and radiation. Sometimes it's linear, sometimes not, but it's usually monotonic (always increasing with $\Delta T$).

There are find a few specialized contradictions.

For example: the [Leidenfrost effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect). In that case the cooling rate of a surface by the boiling of a liquid will increase with temperature to a point, before dropping. The boiling process becomes so intense that a layer of pure vapor forms between the solid and the liquid, acting as an insulator and actually reducing the total heat transfer rate.

I don't know of any other contradictions, but would be keen to hear from others on the subject!

Comment: Ok, so I see that it varies depending on the scenario. Thanks for your time!